# How to get and display data from database without refresh page using ajax and django

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I want to get and display data from database to my page using django and ajax.
This is my view :

```
def getMessages(request, sender_id, receiver_id):
    if request.user.profile == 'A':
        chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id) | Q(receiver_id=sender_id)).all()
    elif request.user.profile == 'C':
        chat = Chat.objects.filter(Q(sender_id=sender_id,receiver_id=receiver_id) | Q(sender_id=receiver_id,receiver_id=sender_id))
    return JsonResponse({"chat":list(chat.values())})
```

And This is my javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
        setInterval(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url : "{% url 'getMessages/{{request.user.id}}/to/{{receiver_user.id}}'}",
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $("#display").empty();
                    for (var key in response.chat)
                    {
                        var temp='<div class="msg-box {% if request.user == msg.sender %} right {% else %} left {% endif %}"><div class="details"><p class="msg">{{ msg.message }}</p><p class="date">{{ msg.msg_time }}</p></div></div>';
                        $("#display").append(temp);
                    }
                },
                error: function(response){
                    console.log('An error occured')
                }
            });
        },1000);
    });
```

And this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<int:sender_id>/to/<int:receiver_id>',views.chat),
    path('send/', views.send, name='send'),
    path('getMessages/<int:sender_id>/to/<int:receiver_id>', views.getMessages, name='getMessages'),
]
```

I try these codes but it doesn't work.

The if in my temp variable doesn't work correctly.
This is my view :

```
def send(request):
    if request.POST['msg'] !=  '':
        message = request.POST['msg']
        sender = request.POST['sender']
        receiver = request.POST['receiver']
        Chat.objects.create(message=message,sender_id=sender,receiver_id=receiver)

    return HttpResponse('Message sent successfully')
```

And this is my form :

```
<form id="post-form" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="input-msg">
                <input type="hidden" name="sender" id="sender" value="{{request.user.id}}">
                <input type="hidden" name="receiver" id="receiver" value="{{receiver_user.id}}">
                <input type="text" name="msg" id="msg" placeholder="Enter Your Message...">
                <button type="submit" id="send"><i class="fa-solid fa-paper-plane"></i></button>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: This may be because you need to give `url` correctly, give it as `url: "{% url 'getMessages' request.user.id receiver_user.id %}"`, if this doesn't work give actual route as `url: "/getMessages/{{request.user.id}}/to/{{reciver_user.id}}/"`, don't forget to give `/` at the beginning and end of route, these things you have to do in jQuery's `url`. And There is no need to apply `all()` after filtering that makes no sense.

Comment: This url is worked for me . But the if inside this div "<div class="msg-box {% if request.user == msg.sender %} right {% else %} left {% endif %}"><div class="details"><p class="msg">{{ msg.message }}</p><p class="date">{{ msg.msg_time }}</p></div></div>" always give the left class. I don't know why ?

Comment: Through your logic this could be because your current logged in user which is in `request.user` is not sender of message. Can you share your view of this?

Comment: This is my view :def send(request):
    if request.POST['msg'] !=  '':
        message = request.POST['msg']
        sender = request.POST['sender']
        receiver = request.POST['receiver']
        Chat.objects.create(message=message,sender_id=sender,receiver_id=receiver)

    return HttpResponse('Message sent successfully')

Comment: Update it in question.